# What should I do when someone incorrectly marked two of my questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87928/what-size-heat-shrink-tubing-for-splicing-lamp-wire-spt-2-18-2-awg) about finding the right heat shrink tubing size for a project.  Someone posted an answer akin to "You shouldn't be doing this project" and was initially unresponsive for further discussion on why I shouldn't do it.  Feeling that the safety of the project was a completely different question than how to measure tubing, I posted [this second question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87989/safest-way-to-contain-spliced-lamp-cord) to garner responses and why the project is unsafe and how it might be done safely.  Now, the person who answered the first question is trying to close my second question as a duplicate when in fact the second question is a completely different question which just happens to have been inspired from commentary on the first.

In addition, the person marking the duplicates seems to exhibit the "noob bullying" which is sometimes such a problem over on Stack Overflow.  The sentiment seems to be that the answer is "don't do this because I said so" rather than sharing knowledge about *why* one shouldn't do it.  My nerve to ask why seems to now be getting downvotes from the user in question.

Finally, the answer on my first question doesn't attempt to address how to properly size heat shrink tubing (which someone else might find useful in the future even if the details and safety of their project are completely different).  So, even if the poster feels his answer addresses my other question, it's not on the appropriate question.  I have since found more information on solving my initial question and will be posting my own answer once the appropriate time window elapses.

The bottom line is, these are completely different questions which I'm now taking reputation hits for posting and having the gall to ask for more information.  What should I do about this?

Comment: Thankfully, SE's built in anti-abuse process reversed most of the unwarranted downvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply explain in the comments and possibly the question itself why you believe your question is not a duplicate. Questions get flagged fairly often by some community members, but not enough to cause the question to be placed on hold. This is why SE included the thresholds to make sure your question wouldn't get closed in these situations. If at some point your question gets closed, you can edit the question with your reasoning why it is unique from the other question and it will be placed in the review queue for community members to decide if your question should be reopened. And you always have the option to flag your question for moderator attention.

Any reputation hits you'll see from one user are more than undone by other community members upvoting your questions. The system is designed to place a much higher value on the upvotes.